# Are Isomorphic Hilbert Spaces Still Solutions

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces

So I was wondering say that you have solutions to some ODE, $y_n$ with eigenvalues of $\lambda_n $. Well, the linear combinations of these solutions are also solutions to the original ODE ( i.e. $ \sum c_ny_n $ are also solutions)

So basically you have a Hilbert space of solutions. Now, my question is what about spaces that are isomorphic to this Hilbert space. What is their relationship to the original ODE? Are these still solutions to the original ODE? Will each eigenfunction have the same eigenvalue? From what I've seen in the literature I believe the answer is yes but I want to make sure that what I though is correct. Thanks.